# media queries are not being applied on site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am new to this and i'm probably doing something wrong

This is my css with my media queries:

```
.box h3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11%;
    top: 12%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0rem 1rem 1.9rem #888888;
    z-index: 10;
}

.box p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11%;
    top: 38%;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0rem 1rem 1.9rem black;
    z-index: 10;
}

@media (min-width: 97rem;) {
.box h3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11%;
    top: 12%;
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0rem 1rem 1.9rem #888888;
    z-index: 10;
}

.box p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 11%;
    top: 38%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0rem 1rem 1.9rem black;
    z-index: 10;
}
}
```

I only am chaning the font size to test my code but it doesn't work.

I have added the viewport tag in my html head.

Edit: [image: import added]

Comment: Need more code. What does the import look like?

Comment: Can you be more specific? what's your import?

Comment: What does your `viewport` and `link` tags look like

Comment: I added my import, the code you see is in index.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used px instead of rem and now it works, is this explainable?

```
@media (min-width: 970px) {
```

Comment: Yes, the missing semicolon. See Tomasz answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

`@media (min-width: 97rem;) {`

try this:

`@media all and (min-width: 97rem) {`

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you remove the semicolon at the end of the `min-width` statement.

```
@media (min-width: 97rem)
```